# android detecting touch event in a layout with many children

Tags: android

I have a linearlayout with a header view followed by a listview and another view (say view A) below the list. I want to toggle the visibility if View A when either the header or the list is touched. For this I had set an onTouchListener on the linearLayout but the on touch method doesnot seem to be called

Answer (score 0):

You most likely want to have an overriding [onTouchEvent(MotionEvent)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#onTouchEvent%28android.view.MotionEvent%29) method in your activity.